Weird fonts after installing powerline fonts
I installed powerline fonts for my zsh terminal, but after that I have weird fonts in Sublime, Remmina, status code in Firefox network, etc.
In most places everything works fine, and the terminal fine too.
How can I fix it?
I did this:
fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts
cp fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
sudo apt install python-fontforge
sudo apt install python3-fontforge
curl https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts.git
./droid.sh

Sublime:

Remmina terminal:

Firefox:


Your question lacks details. For example what version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you know if the fonts work with the unstated version? Have you contacted the people who maintain the github to get assistance as it is their software.
